# Git revert or hard reset

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

Situation is this.
I have made my own commits to public repo and client thought it would be good idea to interfere.

So he changed some files, added his own and deleted some of mine.

To be clear I want to push everything to public repo same as it was with my last commit with some minor changes of my own and discard everything he has done.

When I do `git reset --hard <commit_id>` I can't push to public repo.

I have tried also `git pull origin master --rebase` but this has no affect.

I still see his added files and directories and mine still deleted.

How can I fix this to completely revert and push upstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to completely reset your local copy to what's on the server, you need to first get the recent commits:

```
git fetch
```

And then hard reset your branch to the top of the remote branch. Assuming the branch in question is named `master`, you should first check it out, and then hard reset to `origin/master`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

---

On the other hand, if you would like to set the origin's master branch to whatever your local branch is (not recommended), you can force a push:

```
git push --force
```

Comment: Forcing a push after hard reset was the solution in this case. Thank you.